# Spirit qi parsing to an Abstract Syntax Tree for nested functions

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, abstract-syntax-tree, nested-function

I am trying to create a parser using boost's spirit qi parser. It is parsing a string that contains three types of values. A constant, a variable, or a function. The functions can be nested inside of each other. The test string is `f(a, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)`, where `a-e` are constants, `f-r` are functions, and `s-z` are variables. I successfully created a rule that can correctly parse the expression. The trouble arose when I changed the function parsing the rule into a [grammar](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/grammar.html). There were several errors that I was able to fix. I almost got the grammar to parse the expression and turn it into an abstract syntax tree I created. However I got this error about a file contained in the boost library and I could not figure out where it is coming from because I don't understand the compiler message. I was following the example put up on the website for putting data from a parser to a struct using the employee example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/employee.cpp

*main.cpp*

```
#include "Parser.h"
#include "Term.h"

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Unification Algorithm" << endl << endl;

    string phrase = "f(a, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)";
    string::const_iterator itr = phrase.begin();
    string::const_iterator last = phrase.end();

    cout << phrase << endl;

    // Parser grammar
    Parser<string::const_iterator> g;

    // Output data
    Expression expression;

    if (phrase_parse(itr, last, g, boost::spirit::ascii::space, expression))
    {
        cout << "Expression parsed." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not parse expression." << endl;
    }
}
```

*Parser.h*

```c++
#ifndef _Parser_h_
#define _Parser_h_

#include "Term.h"

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, Expression(), ascii::space_type>
{
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(expression)
    {
        using qi::char_;

        const_char = char_("a-eA-E");
        fn_char = char_("f-rF-R");
        var_char = char_("s-zS-Z");

        basic_fn = fn_char >> char_('(') >> (const_char | var_char) % char_(',') >> char_(')');
        first_fn_wrapper = fn_char >> char_('(') >> (basic_fn | const_char | var_char) % char_(',') >> char_(')');
        nested_fn = fn_char >> char_('(') >> (first_fn_wrapper | const_char | var_char) % char_(',') >> char_(')');

        expression = nested_fn >> char_("=") >> nested_fn;
    }
    // Constant character a - e
    qi::rule<Iterator, T_Cons, ascii::space_type> const_char;
    // Function character f - r
    qi::rule<Iterator, char(), ascii::space_type> fn_char;
    // Variable character s - z
    qi::rule<Iterator, T_Var, ascii::space_type> var_char;
    // Allows for basic function parsing eg. f(x, y, z)
    qi::rule<Iterator, T_Fn, ascii::space_type> basic_fn;
    // Allows for single nested functions eg. f(g(x), y, z)
    qi::rule<Iterator, T_Fn, ascii::space_type> first_fn_wrapper;
    // Allows for fully nested functions eg. f(g(x, h(y)), z) and so on
    qi::rule<Iterator, T_Fn, ascii::space_type> nested_fn;
    // Full rule for a nested function expression
    qi::rule<Iterator, Expression, ascii::space_type> expression;
};
#endif // _Parser_h_
```

*Term.h*

```c++
#ifndef _Term_h_
#define _Term_h_

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Term
{
    char name;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Term, (char, name))

struct T_Cons : Term
{

};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(T_Cons, (char, name))

struct T_Var : Term
{

};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(T_Var, (char, name))

struct T_Fn : Term
{
    std::vector<Term> * params;

    T_Fn() { params = new std::vector<Term>(); }

    ~T_Fn() { delete params; }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(T_Fn, (std::vector<Term>*, params))

struct Expression
{
    Term lh_term;
    Term rh_term;
};

 BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Expression, (char, name) (Term, lh_term) (Term, rh_term))

#endif // _Term_h_
```

I cannot link the entire error message from the compiler because it is extremely long, but here are the last few. These are the compile errors that it gave:

```
boost_1_46_0\boost\mpl\assert.hpp|360|error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ (boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>::grammar(const boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator_, T1_, T2_, T3_, T4_>&, const string&) [with Iterator_ = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >; T1_ = Expression; T2_ = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::asci|
boost_1_46_0\boost\proto\extends.hpp|540|error: use of deleted function 'boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Expression(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> > >, 0l>:|
boost_1_46_0\boost\proto\detail\expr0.hpp|165|error: no matching function for call to 'boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, Expression(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type> >::reference()'|
```

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with term. I only have the two other structs because I want to differentiate between a constant and a variable later. The function term is inherited from the terms because it needs to have nesting capabilities. That has been the biggest struggle for this project is to get a function which can contain another function inside itself.

Comment: That is probably true. That is what my professor said I should use but I was already trying to use boost to get there, and I have the same impression than what you just said. I just wanted to salvage what I had done first. Do you know any tutorials to get me started with lex and yacc?  I looked quickly online and all I got were the linux counterpart and tutorials written for c.

Comment: Actually you could even do it without lexx and yacc. Give me a few hours and I could probably come up with a vanilla c++ solution, if you're interested.

Comment: @kuroineko I'm interested :)

Comment: could you give me a link to your actual assignment description, so that I don't waste too much time chasing my tail? :)

Comment: @user2716722 just show us the grammar. I've given some generic advice in my answer, but in order to "salvage what you have" I'd need to know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I think boost (as well as lex and yacc) are simply overkill for this task, and the overkill is getting in the way of solving the problem. See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769, for how to write recursive descent parsers</a> in a really straightforward way.  There's a link there that shows how to integrate AST construction.   Instead of constructing an AST, you can replace that code with code that evaluates an expression directly.

Comment: well I know that you already made the solution, which is fantastically helpful by the way. But I am working to create a unification algorithm that gets it's input from the parser. It is a simple task but it has been getting daunting quickly

Answer (score 5):

> **UPDATE** Showing a simplified parser with a a recursive ast parsing the sample expression shown

As always, the assertion message leads to exactly the problem:

```
        // If you see the assertion below failing then the start rule
        // passed to the constructor of the grammar is not compatible with
        // the grammar (i.e. it uses different template parameters).
        BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MSG(
            (is_same<start_type, rule<Iterator_, T1_, T2_, T3_, T4_> >::value)
          , incompatible_start_rule, (rule<Iterator_, T1_, T2_, T3_, T4_>));
```

So it tells you you should match the grammar with the start rule: you have

```
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, Expression(), ascii::space_type>
```

but

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Expression, ascii::space_type> expression;
```

Clearly you forgot parentheses there:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Expression(), ascii::space_type> expression;
```

### Guidelines when using generic libraries:

Some of these "rules" are generically applicable, with the exception of no. 2 which is specifically related to Boost Spirit:

1. baby steps; start small (empty, even)
2. start with the AST to match the grammar exactly
3. build gradually,
4. compiling every step along the way

### UPDATE

Here's a much simplified grammar. As mentioned, in the "first rules of spirit" just before, start with the AST to match the grammar exactly:

```
namespace ast {

    namespace tag {
        struct constant;
        struct variable;
        struct function;
    }

    template <typename Tag> struct Identifier { char name; };

    using Constant = Identifier<tag::constant>;
    using Variable = Identifier<tag::variable>;
    using Function = Identifier<tag::function>;

    struct FunctionCall;

    using Expression = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        Constant,
        Variable,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<FunctionCall>
    >::type;

    struct FunctionCall {
        Function function;
        std::vector<Expression> params;
    };

    struct Equation {
        Expression lhs, rhs;
    };
}
```

Of course this could be *much simpler* still since all identifiers are just `char` and you could do the switching dynamically (**[impression](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10378816/)**).

Now, the grammar will have to follow. **1.** Keep it simple **2.** Format carefully **3.** Match the ast directly, **4.** add debug macros:

```
template <typename It, typename Skipper = ascii::space_type>
    struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, ast::Equation(), Skipper>
{
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(equation_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        constant_ = qi::eps >> char_("a-eA-E");
        function_ = qi::eps >> char_("f-rF-R");
        variable_ = qi::eps >> char_("s-zS-Z");

        function_call = function_ >> '(' >> -(expression_ % ',') >> ')';
        expression_   = constant_ | variable_ | function_call;
        equation_     = expression_ >> '=' >> expression_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((constant_)(function_)(variable_)(function_call)(expression_)(equation_))
    }
    qi::rule<It, ast::Constant()> constant_;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Function()> function_;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Variable()> variable_;

    qi::rule<It, ast::FunctionCall(), Skipper> function_call;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Expression(),   Skipper> expression_;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Equation(),     Skipper> equation_;
};
```

> Note how the comments have become completely unneeded. Also note how recursively using `expression_` solved your biggest headache!

### Full Program

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2252a606d3429967)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

namespace ast {

    namespace tag {
        struct constant;
        struct variable;
        struct function;
    }

    template <typename Tag> struct Identifier { char name; };

    using Constant = Identifier<tag::constant>;
    using Variable = Identifier<tag::variable>;
    using Function = Identifier<tag::function>;

    struct FunctionCall;

    using Expression = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        Constant,
        Variable,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<FunctionCall>
    >::type;

    struct FunctionCall {
        Function function;
        std::vector<Expression> params;
    };

    struct Equation {
        Expression lhs, rhs;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Constant, (char, name))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Variable, (char, name))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Function, (char, name))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::FunctionCall, (ast::Function, function)(std::vector<ast::Expression>, params))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::Equation, (ast::Expression, lhs)(ast::Expression, rhs))

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = ascii::space_type>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, ast::Equation(), Skipper>
{
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(equation_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        constant_ = qi::eps >> char_("a-eA-E");
        function_ = qi::eps >> char_("f-rF-R");
        variable_ = qi::eps >> char_("s-zS-Z");

        function_call = function_ >> '(' >> -(expression_ % ',') >> ')';
        expression_   = constant_ | variable_ | function_call;
        equation_     = expression_ >> '=' >> expression_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((constant_)(function_)(variable_)(function_call)(expression_)(equation_))
    }
    qi::rule<It, ast::Constant()> constant_;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Function()> function_;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Variable()> variable_;

    qi::rule<It, ast::FunctionCall(), Skipper> function_call;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Expression(),   Skipper> expression_;
    qi::rule<It, ast::Equation(),     Skipper> equation_;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Unification Algorithm\n\n";

    std::string const phrase = "f(a, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)";
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It itr = phrase.begin(), last = phrase.end();

    std::cout << phrase << std::endl;

    Parser<It> g;
    ast::Equation parsed;

    if (phrase_parse(itr, last, g, ascii::space, parsed)) {
        std::cout << "Expression parsed.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Could not parse equation.\n";
    }

    if (itr != last) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(itr,last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a cutie. Clearly this boost thingie can shine when you know how to use it. Would you consider adding an example of syntactical tree use, for instance printing back the program from the AST like I did?

Comment: I might if I find some time tonight :)

Answer (score 3):

## A vanilla C++ solution <sub>(as per popular request)</sub>

I compiled it with MSVC 2013.
Lack of unrestricted unions support lead me to duplicate the 3 possible values of an argument.

There are workarounds for this limitation, but <sub>(like so many other things in C++)</sub> they are rather messy, so I kept them out to limit code obfuscation.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// possible token types
enum tTokenType {
    T_CONST,  // s-z
    T_VAR,    // a-e
    T_FUNC,   // f-r
    T_EQUAL,  // =
    T_COMMA,  // ,
    T_OBRACE, // (
    T_CBRACE, // )
    T_SPACE,  // ' ' or '\t'
    T_ERROR,  // anything but spaces
    T_EOI     // end of input
};

// tokens
struct tToken {
    tTokenType _type;  // lexical element type
    char       _value; // the actual const/var/func letter
    size_t     _index; // position in translation unit

    static const string constants, variables, functions, spacing;
    static const char * type_name[];

    tToken(tTokenType t, size_t index) : _type(t), _value(0), _index(index) {}

    static tTokenType type(char c)
    {
        if (constants.find(c) != string::npos) return T_CONST;
        if (variables.find(c) != string::npos) return T_VAR;
        if (functions.find(c) != string::npos) return T_FUNC;
        if (spacing  .find(c) != string::npos) return T_SPACE;
        if (c == '=')                          return T_EQUAL;
        if (c == ',')                          return T_COMMA;
        if (c == '(')                          return T_OBRACE;
        if (c == ')')                          return T_CBRACE;
        return T_ERROR;
    }

    tToken(char c, size_t index) : _value(c), _index(index)
    {
        _type = type(c);
    }

    void croak(tTokenType type)
    {
        string err(_index - 1, '-');
        cerr << err << "^ expecting " << type_name[(int)type] << "\n";
    }
};
const string tToken::variables("abcde");
const string tToken::functions("fghijklmnopqr");
const string tToken::constants("stuvwxyz");
const string tToken::spacing  (" \t");
const char * tToken::type_name[] = { "constant", "variable", "function", "=", ",", "(", ")", "space", "error", "end of input" };

// parser
class Parser {
    friend class Compiler;
    string _input; // remaining program input
    size_t _index; // current token index (for error tracking)

    void skip_spaces(void)
    {
        while (_input.length() != 0 && tToken::type(_input[0]) == T_SPACE) next();
    }

    void next(void)
    {
        _input.erase(0, 1);
        _index++;
    }

public:
    void read (string program)
    {
        _input = program;
        _index = 0;
        skip_spaces();
    }

    tToken get(void)
    {
        tToken res = peek();
        next();
        skip_spaces();
        return res;
    }

    tToken peek(void)
    {
        if (_input.length() == 0) return tToken(T_EOI, _index);
        return tToken (_input[0], _index);
    }

    tToken accept(tTokenType type)
    {
        tToken t = get();
        return (t._type == type) ? t : tToken (T_ERROR, _index-1);
    }

    bool consume(tTokenType type)
    {
        tToken t = get();
        bool res = t._type == type;
        if (!res) t.croak(type);
        return res;
    }
};

// syntactic elements
struct tSyntacticElement {
    char name;
    bool valid;

    tSyntacticElement() : name('?'), valid(false) {}
    tSyntacticElement(char c) : name(c), valid(false) {}
};

class tConstant : private tSyntacticElement  {
    friend class tArgument;
    tConstant() {}
    tConstant(tToken t) : tSyntacticElement(t._value) { }
};

class tVariable : private tSyntacticElement  {
    friend class tArgument;
    tVariable() {}
    tVariable(tToken t) : tSyntacticElement(t._value) { }

};

class tFunCall : private tSyntacticElement {
    friend class Compiler;
    friend class tProgram;
    friend class tArgument;
    vector<tArgument>params;

    tFunCall() {}
    tFunCall(tToken t) : tSyntacticElement(t._value) { }
    void add_argument(tArgument a);

    string dump(void);
};

class tArgument {
    friend class Compiler;
    friend class tProgram;
    friend class tFunCall;
    tTokenType type;

    // MSVC 2013 does not support unrestricted unions, so for the 
    // sake of simplicity I'll leave it as 3 separate attributes
    tConstant c; 
    tVariable v;
    tFunCall  f;

    tArgument() {}

    tArgument(tToken val) : type(val._type)
    {
        if (val._type == T_CONST) c = val;
        if (val._type == T_VAR  ) v = val;
    }
    tArgument(tFunCall  f) : type(T_FUNC ), f(f) {}

    string dump(void)
    {
        if (type == T_VAR)   return string("$") + v.name;
        if (type == T_CONST) return string("#") + c.name;
        if (type == T_FUNC)  return f.dump();
        return "!";
    }
};

class tProgram  {
    friend class Compiler;
    tArgument left;
    tArgument right;
    bool valid;

    string dump(void) { return left.dump() + " = " + right.dump(); }
};

// syntactic analyzer

void tFunCall::add_argument(tArgument a) { params.push_back(a); }

string tFunCall::dump(void)
{
    string res(1, name);
    res += '(';
    // it's 2015 and still no implode() in C++...
    for (size_t i = 0; i != params.size(); i++)
    {
        res += params[i].dump();
        if (i != params.size() - 1) res += ',';
    }
    res += ')';
    return res;
}

class Compiler {
    Parser parser;
    tProgram program;

    tFunCall parse_function(void)
    {
        tToken f = parser.accept(T_FUNC);
        tFunCall res (f);
        parser.accept(T_OBRACE);
        for (;;)
        {
            tArgument a = parse_argument();
            res.add_argument(a);
            tToken next = parser.get();
            if (next._type == T_CBRACE) break;
            if (next._type != T_COMMA) return res;
        }
        res.valid = true;
        return res;
    }

    tArgument parse_argument(void)
    {
        tToken id = parser.peek();
        if (id._type == T_FUNC)  return parse_function();
        id = parser.get();
        if (id._type == T_CONST) return id;
        if (id._type == T_VAR)   return id;
        return tArgument(tToken (T_ERROR, id._index));
    }

public:
    void analyze(string input)
    {
        parser.read(input);
        cerr << input << "\n";

        program.left = parse_argument();
        program.valid &= parser.consume(T_EQUAL);
        program.right = parse_argument();
        program.valid &= parser.consume(T_EOI);
    }

    string dump(void)
    {
        return program.dump();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Compiler compiler;
//  compiler.analyze("f(a, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)");
    compiler.analyze(argv[1]);
    cout << compiler.dump();
    return 0;
}
```

### Grammar

Given the rather terse problem definition, I invented a grammar that should at least match the test input:

```
program : argument = argument
argument: variable
        | constant
        | fun_call
fun_call: fun_name ( arg_list )
arg_list: argument
        | argument , arg_list
```

### Parsing

Given the simplicity of the syntax, parsing is pretty straightforward.
Each character is basically something valid, a space or something invalid.
Spaces are silently consumed, so that the analyzer only gets useful tokens to process.

### Analyze

Since I'm doing this barehanded, I simply define a function for each grammatical rule (program, fun_call, arg_list, argument).

The grammar is predictive (can't remember how it's called in posh books, LL1 maybe?) and there are no arithmetic expressions so the code is relatively lightweight.

### Error reporting

Bah, just the barest minimum, and I did not really test it.

Proper error handling can easily double code size (even with yacc), so I drew the line early.

Invalid characters will be replaced by "!", and some expected symbols will be pointed at in a semblance of vintage C compilers output.

There are absolutely no re-synchronization attempts, so a typo inside a function call (especially a braces imbalance) will likely cast the rest of the translation unit to the bin.

### Using the hard earned syntactic tree

The mighty compiler manages to spit out an equivalent of the input.

Just to show that something was done beside trimming white spaces, variables are preceded by a '$' and constants by a '#' (showing a deplorable lack of imagination).

### Sample output

```
ExpressionCompiler "f(a) = z"
f(a) = z
f($a) = #z

ExpressionCompiler "f(a) = f(c,z)"
f(a) = f(c,z)
f($a) = f($c,#z)

ExpressionCompiler "f(a, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)"
f(a, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)
f($a,$b) = f(g(#z,#x),g(#x,h(#x)),$c)

ExpressionCompiler "f(a, b) + f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)"
f(a, b) + f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)
-------^ expecting =
f($a,$b) = f(g(#z,#x),g(#x,h(#x)),$c)

ExpressionCompiler "f(A, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)"
f(A, b) = f(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)
f(!,$b) = f(g(#z,#x),g(#x,h(#x)),$c)

ExpressionCompiler "f(a, b) = K(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)"
f(a, b) = K(g(z, x), g(x, h(x)), c)
----------^ expecting end of input
f($a,$b) = !
```

Comment: Looks good. I'm not too sure what the compiler adds, but anyways, it does show techniques :)

Comment: It has the beauty of all things with no practical use. Art for art's sake, as we say in France :)

Comment: this answer helps me a lot more than the boost example. I only used boost because I thought it would be easier to make and use. The vanilla example will actually make me understand what is going on with the code instead of the library doing the work for me. My professor also told me that he could be updating the problem statement to include more complex inputs, and this solution would be easier for me to change than the boost code would.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help. Be aware that handmade parsers are quite limited, though. They will work OK on a small grammar, but having to define a function for each rule can increase code volume real quick. And bulky code is bug country. This boost thingie looks quite powerful once you know how to use it, and by studying its design you could probably learn a thing or two. It should certainly allow to parse a more complicated grammar with far less code than my barebone solution.